# assigning $_GET and $_POST to single variable

Tags: php

I am currently doing this:

`$_GET` Request

```
$process = @$_GET['data_process'];
$id = @$_GET['data_id'];
$link = @$_GET['data_page'];
```

`$_POST` Request

```
$process = @$_POST['data_process'];
$id = @$_POST['data_id'];
$link = @$_POST['data_page'];
```

Although it looks messy to me.  How can I refine this process?

Comment: Why you want all this diffrent values in a single variable??

Comment: @PragneshChauhan What difference will it make??

Comment: error suppression (use of the `@` symbol) is an indication of poor program logic and/or design... also - you should be definite that people will either hit a URL with a GET or a POST request - it is incredibly rare that it is appropriate to be able to accept both.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan `$_REQUEST` should only ever be used if you want a value from either `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: Using the @ is nice because I hate seeing `if(isset($_GET['id']))` all the time, it seems incredibly long winded and annoying.

Comment: @HorusKol Sometimes It is easier for me to send data via `<a href>` rather than post everything through forms.  This way I can funnel all my GET and POST data into one area.

Comment: of course, you're free to do what you like - but I thought you'd appreciate some advice on good practice

Comment: @HorusKol I want the advice! yes please.  And the way I have made my program is that all data goes through a single page - so sometimes it is receiving `$_GET` and sometimes it's receiving `$_POST`, is this not good practice then?

Comment: @HorusKol for instance I had a huge form that was populated with database info, and throughout that I had in the `value=` fields I had `@db['id']` for example, because the form was not always populated.  Would you use `isset` to check them all and echo then? It seems long-winded and messy to me.

Comment: I wouldn't leave it until I was rendering the form to know if I had data to put into the form from the database. As for making it all go through a single page: that is definitely not good practice - you are eventually going to end up with a 10,000+ line block of spaghetti code. Get yourself a copy of (this book)[http://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1349781625&sr=1-1&keywords=php+patterns+objects+practice] to start with

Comment: @HorusKol Okay I will check out the book - but that central page is very well scructured with the data_process going into a giant `switch` statement, defining exactly what to do, Wheras before I was receiving data from all the place and in many different places.  And the form - What if you want a blank form for the user to input data? You would write the form out twice in different places to give to the user? One populated and one blank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i do

```
function POST($key) {
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
}

function GET($key) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : null;
}
```

Simple Usage

```
$process = GET('data_process');
$id = GET('data_id');
$link = GET('data_page');

$process = POST('data_process');
$id = POST('data_id');
$link = POST('data_page');
```

Edit: In this way you can easly assign a default value. Example:

```
function POST($key,$default=null) {
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;
}

$process = POST('p','defaultvalue');
```

@yes123 wanted more here you have it ..

```
$R = new REQUEST();
$process = $R['data_process'];
$id = $R['data_id'];
$link = $R['data_page'];
```

Class Used

```
class REQUEST implements \ArrayAccess {
    private $request = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->request = $_REQUEST;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->request[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->request[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->request[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->request[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->request[$offset]) ? $this->request[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added an example on how to easly assign default value (widely used)

Comment: As a sidenote from the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.rules.php#userlandnaming.rules): PHP reserves all symbols starting with `__` as magical. It is recommended that you do not create symbols starting with `__` in PHP unless you want to use documented magical functionality

Comment: @yes123 .. Thanks i added one for you tooo

Comment: @baba: the funny thing is that if you read carefully OP questions he asks something else :D

Comment: He basically just wants to use extract :D

Comment: lol ... are you sure ........ I was thinking he asked `How can I refine this process?` @yes123

Comment: I like the top two functions, they are clean and work exactly as I need.  However, maybe it might be nice to combine them into one - with priority to the POST, if both are set? (which they never would be, just covering all bases)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this to check the variable:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '';
```

Don't use **@** to hide the notices. You should have a clean code.

Comment: even messier than my original :( ... well, without the hidden error messages anyway.

Comment: Its the common way ;) to prevent notices.